# Linked List in C printing an extra zero

Tags: c, list

I'm trying to learn using pointers, especially with list but I have a problem.
I'm in a little trouble with my linked list.
I can't understand why it prints an extra zero at the top of the list.
Here the code.
Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int val;
    struct Node *next;
};


void insert(struct Node *head, int val);
void print(struct Node *head);

int main(){

    struct Node *head = NULL;

    head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    insert(head, 5);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}


void insert(struct Node *head, int val){
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("Error");
        return;
    }

    struct Node* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    tmp->val = val;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    while(head->next != NULL){
        head = head->next;
    }

    head->next = tmp;


}


void print(struct Node *head){
    while(head != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", head->val);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list looks something like this:

```
+-----------+     +------------------------+     +-------------------------+
| head node | --> | first node in the list | --> | second node in the list | --> ...
+-----------+     +------------------------+     +-------------------------+
```

The extra zero you print is the otherwise unused head node. You should skip it when printing:

```
void print(struct Node *head){
    if (head == NULL)
        return;  // No list

    // Skip the dummy head node
    struct Node *node = head->next;

    while(node != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", node->val);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

---

Another possible solution is to not have a "dummy" head node, and instead let the head node be the first node in the list. This requires changes to the `insert` function and to skip the allocation of the `head` node.

The biggest change is to change the `insert` function to receive the `head` node by *reference* (emulated by using pointers to the head node pointer).

Perhaps something like this:

```
void insert(struct Node **head)
{
    struct Node* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    tmp->val = val;
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        // List is empty, add first node in the list
        *head = tmp;
    else
    {
        // Non-empty list, add at tail
        struct Node *iter = *head;
        while (iter->next != NULL)
            iter = iter->next;

        iter->next = tmp;
    }
}
```

Call like

```
struct Node *head = NULL;
insert(&head, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are always setting the `tmp->val`, but you never set the `head->val`.

In the printing loop, for the first iteration, you're reading an unitialized value. As per your data structure, you should start reading the values from the second node.